# Angular PreloadAllModules for lazyloaded modules is not working

Tags: angular, angular7, jhipster, angular-lazyloading

I have successfully implemented lazy loading for my modules **Products** and **Customers**, and I am able to see the chunks when I navigate to respective routing.

Now I want the above modules to **preload**, which can be done simply by adding

```
{ preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules }
```

But this is not working, The above modules are still loading lazily **(chunks are loading when I navigate to respective modules instead of initial load)**.

---

**This is how Implemented**

*app.module.ts*

```
@NgModule({
 imports: [LazyLoadModule]
})
```

*lazy-load.module.ts*

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot([{
        path: 'products',
        data: {
            preload: false
        },
        loadChildren: './entities/products/products.module#ProductsModule',
    },
    {
        path: 'customers',
        data: {
            preload: true
        },
        loadChildren: './entities/customers/customers.module#CustomersModule',
    }], { useHash: true, preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })]
})
```

However if I add the configuration directly in `app.module.ts`, then it seems to work(I can see the individual chunks at initial load), But my routing paths are not working.

---

**Update**

First I tried with **custom preloading strategy** like this

*preloading-strategy.service.ts*

```
@Injectable()
export class PreloadingStrategyService implements PreloadingStrategy {

    preload(route: Route, load: () => Observable<any>) {
        console.log('Preloading called');
        return route.data && route.data.preload ? load() : of(null);
    }
}
```

*lazy-load.module.ts*

```
{ preloadingStrategy: PreloadingStrategyService }
```

But preload method is never called(No console log printed), So for testing purpose I added **PreloadAllModules**. This also doesn't work as I already explained above.

Comment: can you provide a minimal stackblitz?

Comment: @AakashGarg I tried reproducing it in standalone project, but no issue there(works fine). The issue is with my project.

Comment: in lazy module shouldn't you be using forChild instead of forRoot? I can also see preload flag as false. in any other module you are using any preloading strategy?

Comment: @AakashGarg Yes my end goal is to create **custom preloading strategy** service, But that doesn't work(never called/stopped in debugger). So I added **PreloadAllModules**. Yes I used `forChild` in **Products** and **Customers** Module

Comment: https://coryrylan.com/blog/custom-preloading-and-lazy-loading-strategies-with-angular

Comment: @AakashGarg I have gone through the above article and many others (doesn't work), I have updated my question

Comment: add RouterModule in exports of Lazyloadmodule ngmodule decorator.

Comment: check below how i exported routing module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by `module: "commonjs"` in *tsconfig.json*, It should be `module: "ESNext"`.

[Found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66043577/11719787)

Answer (score 0):

Change your lazy-load.module.ts to

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot([{
        path: 'products',
        data: {
            preload: false
        },
        loadChildren: './entities/products/products.module#ProductsModule',
    },
    {
        path: 'customers',
        data: {
            preload: true
        },
        loadChildren: './entities/customers/customers.module#CustomersModule',
    }], { useHash: true, preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })],
    exports: [RoutingModule]
})
```

Comment: You mean `RouterModule` ?. Added that to exports but still modules are loading lazily(chunks are loading when navigated for both modules).

Comment: you need to provide a proper stackblitz. can't find actual problem area like this.