# Angular lazy loading not working in webpack with @ngtools/webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-lazyloading

**Lazy module is eagerly loading, No separate chunks created for lazy modules**

I created a repo to reproduce the issue

1.Clone https://github.com/sameerthekhans/lazy-load-angular-webpack-temp.git

2.`npm i`

3.`npm start`

4.Output - No chunk files created in `dist` and the module is eagerly loaded in the browser

Additional Info
I used all the latest version of dependencies `Angular - 11.1.1`, `Webpack - 5` and So on...
***Also note I didn't used `angular-router-loader` as [@ngtools/webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngtools/webpack) is used.**

Comment: i cloned your repo and made it work, feel free to give me permission in raronen github and i'll push

Comment: @RazRonen I invited you as collaborator

Comment: pushed the code

Comment: Please include relevant code in the body of the question itself. This question does not include a [mre]. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that in your tsconfig you define `module: "commonjs"`. commonjs doesn't respect dynamic import syntax. You need to change it to `module: "ESNext"` for example that does.

Comment: I also turned on `"moduleResolution": "node"` and changed your webpack typescript to js syntax in order for it to work, but this isn't the main reason for webpack not splitting your code

Comment: Thanks! it worked with above changes, but how do I use import statements?(I would like to use typescript for webpack config)

Comment: webpack is written in javascript so I don't think you actually can, unless you set up a grunt/gulp task to first compile your typescript which is overhead in my opinion

Comment: I think its possible [webpack config as TS](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-languages/#typescript). Only thing is I need to create separate tsconfig for webpack (let me give it a try) Thanks.